# PHP - cannot build array

Tags: php, arrays

First things first. Here's the bad code:

```
public function get_mango($mango_juice) {
    $mango_id       = $this->mango_id;
    $respons   = array(
        'recipient' => [ 'id'   =>  $mango_id ],
        'message'   => [ 'text' => "$mango_juice" ]
    );
    return $respons;
}
```

This is a function of the Mango.php file in which is contained the Mango class. Mango is used in the main page (*index.php*) to provide an answer to what comes from the outside internet (in this case, Facebook).

The code I provided seems to be bad because I checked that `$mango_id` has a value after I assigned `$this->mango_id` but, mysteriously, `$respons` is neither `NULL` nor `EMPTY`! So many `error_log("$poor_variable");` brought me to this. As an example, if I `error_log(var_dump($respons))` the only thing I get is nothing, pure nothing. So you can imagine that nothing is returned.
I performed the error_logs *in the right place*, so after instantiate the variables described.

If I try to build the array in the following piece of code (actually the part is commented, obviously) **it works!** *"Fantastic!" I said after I noticed that using this workaround the code worked, but I can't put the construction of the array in the main *index.php* because I will lose all the organization the OOP programming method provides you!

```
if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'])) {
    $sender_id      = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];

    //the mango class - the constructor put the $sender_id in the mango_id property
    $mango          = new Mango($sender_id);
    //user_input
    $messageText    = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
    //I haven't showed this method, but imagine this returns a clean, always non-empty string.
    $mango_answer   = $mango->talk($messageText);
    //This is where I call the incriminated piece of code.
    $res       = $mango->compose_answer($mango_answer);
    /**$response = [
        'recipient' => [ 'id'   =>  $sender_id ],
        'message'   => [ 'text' => "$res" ]
    ];*/

    $ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token='.FBHandler::ACCESS_TOKEN);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($res));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

**What's happening?**

*PS: I noticed that there were many questions related to **PHP not building arrays**, many of them marked as a duplicate of others where the solution provided was too general, like "upgrade your PHP" or too specific. I can neither upgrade nor check my version of PHP. So, please, help me!*

[EDIT] *My PHP version is 5.3.29*. Thanks to @RiggsFolly.

Comment: try commenting $mango_id = $this->mango_id; and use hard code value just to debug $mango_id = 123;

Comment: try using var_dump($response) or print_r($response) and tell me what you get in response

Comment: Here is how to check your version of PHP `<?php echo 'PHP Version ' . phpversion(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly. I'm checking right now. It's the  5.3.29. I'm updating right now the post.

Comment: Thanks, @Jabs. I tried but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are using PHP5.3.29 then the new array syntax `[]` does not work

This code

```
$response = [
        'recipient' => [ 'id'   =>  $sender_id ],
        'message'   => [ 'text' => $res ]
    ];
```

Generates this error in 5.3.29

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in D:\PHP-SOURCE\tst.php on line 5

As would the Mango code in the function you mention

This code would work

```
$response = array(
    'recipient' => array( 'id'   =>  $sender_id ),
    'message'   => array( 'text' => $res )
);
```

Comment: Yes, this works! I dunno why I could not see this error in the logs, but the fix is the correct one. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please read the docs for [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). It returns `void`, which is your "pure nothing" you are logging with `error_log(var_dump($respons))`.

Use one of [print_r($respons,true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), [var_export($respons, true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php), [json_encode($respons)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or similar which return a string that can be logged.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the answer to my question. Thank you for providing me this correction, but I didn't ask for a correct way to debug. I'm asking why I cannot build an array. Also if I don't debug it, the function returns this pure nothing.

Comment: My point is it returns a valid array, you just fail to log it properly, which leads you to wrong assumptions.

Comment: yes, I was also asking same in comments to question to find whether array is valid or not